# Resizing a frame when clicking a button

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jframe

I've recently started a Java course to get familiar with programming. So sorry if this seems to be a stupid question. What i'm trying to do is resize the window when a button is clicked.

Code says more then words:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GrowShrink extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public GrowShrink(String title) throws HeadlessException {
        super(title);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton buttonGrow = new JButton("Grow");
        JButton buttonShrink = new JButton("Shrink");
        buttonGrow.addActionListener(this);
        buttonShrink.addActionListener(this);
        add(buttonGrow);
        add(buttonShrink);
        pack();
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Grow")) {
            getContentPane().setSize(600, 600);
            getContentPane().doLayout();
//            getContentPane().repaint();
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Shrink")) {
            getContentPane().setSize(200, 200);
//            getContentPane().revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GrowShrink growShrink = new GrowShrink("Grow and Shrink the frame");
    }
}
```

When I follow the debugger of IntelliJ I can clearly see that the size has become `600x600` when checking the `hight` and `width` after clicking the button `Grow`. However, this doesn't seem to do anything to the window.

Am I missing something here? I've tried with `repaint()`, `doLayout()` and `revalidate()` but not success there.

Comment: Inside `if` and `else` blocks, you should call `GrowShrink.this.setSize(...);GrowShrink.this.repaint();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What i'm trying to do is resize the window when a button is clicked.

Your code is setting the size of the content pane, not the frame. So you need to invoke `setSize(...)` on the frame.

> Am I missing something here? I've tried with repaint(), doLayout() and revalidate() but not success there.

Swing uses layout managers. The layout manager is responsible for setting the size and location of a component based mostly on the "preferred" size of the component and the components added to a panel.

Invoking `revalidate()` will invoke the layout manager, however nothing will change because the preferred size of the components added to the panel hasn't changed.

If the preferred size of the content pane does change when you do revalidate() then you would still need to invoke `pack()` on the frame to take advantage of the recalculated preferred size.

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't know the difference between a JPane and the JFrame. That's clear now thanks to your explanation and the code from @Naruto.